# Ubuntu install from USB issues

Tags: command-line, screen, prompt

I have downloaded Ubuntu to my USB but am having trouble with the install. I reboot my computer and boot from the USB. Then the Ubuntu screen pops up and I select install ( also have tried the demo option)  After all I get is a gray screen with a blinking command prompt? I have tried a few times now this happens everytime with the same result. Does anyone know what could cause this??

thank you

Comment: How did you make the installation USB ?

Comment: I downloaded a universal USB installer, then downloaded the file to the USB. seemed to work booted up said Ubuntu gave me a few options but once you choose install..nothing but gray screen

Answer (score 0):

I am new to linux too. I would go back to the download page of the distro you have selected and check the checksums I think it's called MD5. Most times before you burn the iso the burner shows you the checksums and you should check if they're the same number.

It could be a corrupt iso from a download. I had a problem similar but the difference was it would not even start the install.

Unless your installing a minimal distro of linux without a gui.

I prefer to use **http://www.pendrivelinux.com/** as that seems to be the easiest way to get a distro onto an usb stick. Works for me everytime.

Hope that helped

Comment: Thanks for the info!, actually the "universal USB installer" I used is pendrivelinux. but I will try again

Comment: I prefer using http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ and download the ISO as a torrent. This way it's almost sure the download isn't corrupted, since BitTorrent already uses checksums.

Comment: Yup you're right the pendrive is if you're in a windows os at the time. The unetbootin will do nicely in a linux os. Can get it from the software manager repository.